# What is the Office.Settings storage upper limit?

Tags: office-js

Can we please specify how much data can be stored using office.settings.set API specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=office-js)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the same link for the total available memory.

[image]

Hope it helps